# php session not working in Version 5.1.6

Tags: php, session

Hello My question is very basic one just tell me why this code which is working fine on all others php vesions not working in PHP Version 5.1.6

Code is

"

```
 session_start(); 

if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
$_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
else{

$_SESSION['views']=1;}
echo "Views=". $_SESSION['views'];
```

Plz  reply soon any help will be apprieciable

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['views'] = isset($_SESSION['views']) ? $_SESSION['views']+1 : 1;
```

EDIT : question has been edited when I wrote this, don't know if it will change anything.